# How to prevent scroll when using useSearchParams

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use `useSearchParams` to add a query string to a URL path such as `/some_path?type=1`, where the value `1` of the query string represents the order of items in the list. When I click on one of these items query gets set correctly, but the issue is that screen scrolls to the top. I want to prevent scrolling, how can I do that?

`react-router-dom` version `6.4+`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  

  return (
    <div>
      <ul >
        <li onClick={()=>{
          setSearchParams({type: 1}, {preventScrollReset: true})
        }}>1</li>
         <li onClick={()=>{
          setSearchParams({type: 2},  {preventScrollReset: true})
        }}>1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My router setup/configuration:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { asyncGetListItems } from "./asyncGetListItems";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/list",
    element:<TheAboveListComponent />,
    loader: async () => { return asyncGetListItems() }
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: What router are you using? Scroll restoration works with the new Data APIs. Can you share your router code, the setup/configuration? See [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure the `setSearchParams` is not reloading the page?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your comment! updated my comment, yes using new Data API. appreciate your help

Comment: @Terry double checked and it is NOT reloading the page, thanks!

Comment: I think we may need to see more code, that which is between the router and the `App` component enough to be considered a [mcve]. In other words, enough code to be considered a reproducible example.

Comment: FWIW I am not able to reproduce the behavior you describe in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-kilby-wymmnj?file=/src/App.js). Have you implemented a `ScrollToTop` component somewhere in your app?

Answer (score 1):

When using the `<ScrollRestoration />` component, you need to customize the getKey function to prevent reset scrolling when the location key change (this happens also when the hash change).

Here is an example with ignoring the "search" part of url to set scroll restoration key.

```
<ScrollRestoration getKey={location => location.pathname} />
```